# How to rename many dfs with digit-like column?

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I have 5 dfs called: 
`control1,control2,control3,control4,control5`.

All of these have a `column name 1`. This column name is `int` type.

How can i change this column name for each df to `'CODIGO'` (`str` type).

I tried this:

```
for j in range(1,6):
   exec(f"control{j}=control{j}.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(1, 'CODIGO'))")
```

But does not work. Can you help me please?

Comment: You should use a dictionary or list to store your dataframes. But you should probably change `1` to `"1"` since you are replacing a string, not an int. If you could elaborate on why this method "does not work", that would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
l = [control1, control2, control3, control4, control5]

for df in l:
    df.rename(columns={1:'CODIGO'}, inplace=True)
```